# Can I use my UK provisional Driving Licence as a residence permit?

Tags: visas, uk, driving, turkey, residency

Actually I want to apply for Turkey electronic visa. Moreover as per their requirement I should got valid residence permit of UK or valid schengen vise. I have valid provisional driving license therefore I want to ask you that can i use the provisional driving licence as a residence permit.

Comment: Why would you think that a Driving License would in any way be equivalent to a Residency Permit?

Comment: What citizenship do you hold?

Answer (score 3):

You want to apply for a Turkish visa and using their e-Visa system.  You have a UK Provisional Driving Permit and are asking if it can be presented as a residence permit.

**tl;dr** => no.

One of the requirements for a UK Provisional Driving Permit is that the person be a 'UK Resident'.  In this context, a 'UK Resident' is a person whose leave to remain was issued for a period *longer* than 6 months, such as a 'Category D' visa.

Commonly, people use their foreign passport along with their **Biometric Residence Permit** (BRP) for this (although other, more senior, documents are accepted)...

[image: brp]

The DVLA will then issue a provisional license that is keyed to the BRP in *their system only*.  When they issued this to you, you should have received a brochure explaining that a provisional license cannot be used outside of the UK and relies upon your immigration status to remain valid, that would have been a signal.

More to the point, the provisional license does not have all of the fraud detection measures that more senior documents have.  They are easy to forge.

For these reasons, the UK Border Force will not recognise the provisional license as evidence of immigration status, and nobody else will either.  Emphatically, it raises the awkward question of 'where's your BRP'?

Since you successfully applied for a provisional licence and assuming that your immigration status in the UK is still legitimate, you can simply use your BRP to apply for a Turkish visa.  If you are unable to use your BRP (ILR, PR, etc), then you'll need to ask a different question.

A UK Provisional Driving License will not work.